# How to verify Aadhar number and name of user in mobile (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, aadhaar

I want to create mobile application in which user will enter his Aadhar number and Name and age/Birth date.

How do I want to verify the entered details by user with Aadhar number?.

Comment: What you have tried ? found any source or anything ?

Comment: if u want to verify the user details against aadhar you ve to register with UIDAI and get a api. with that api using http calls u can verify

Comment: https://authportal.uidai.gov.in/developer